# Не работает if-else

Tags: javascript

Вот такая вот проблемка.
Написал калькулятор расчета цены, но фильтрация данных не проходит.
Я думаю, это из-за типа данных.
Ведь когда я беру данные из html'a, получаю string, а величины с которыми сравниваю их - number.

```
<p>Ширина :</p>
<input type="text" id="width">

<p>Высота (см): </p>
<input type="text" id="height">

<button id="btn" onclick="getCalc()">Рассчитать</button>

function getCalc() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

    var max_width = 200;
    var min_width = 120;
    var max_height = 240;
    var min_height = 180;

    var result = 0;
    var errors = 0;

    // errors block
    if (width < min_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else if (height < min_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else {
        errors = 0;
    }

    if (width > max_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else if (height > max_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else {
        errors = 0;
    }
    if (errors <= 0) {
        result = (width * 15) + (height * 10.5);
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result + " rub.";
    } else {
        result = "Error.";
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в Вашем коде нет элемента с ID = `price`. Добавил `span`.

Во-вторых, для отслеживания пути исполнения кода полезно добавлять `console.log()`, а для выяснения типа полезно выражение `typeof x`. Пример:

```js
function getCalc() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    console.log(typeof width);

    var max_width = 200;
    var min_width = 120;
    var max_height = 240;
    var min_height = 180;

    var result = 0;
    var errors = 0;

    // errors block
    if (width < min_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        console.log('W <');

    } else if (height < min_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        console.log('H <');

    } else {
        errors = 0;
        console.log('0 <');
    }

    if (width > max_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        console.log('W >');

    } else if (height > max_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        console.log('H >');

    } else {
        errors = 0;
        console.log('0 >');
    }
    if (errors <= 0) {
        result = (width * 15) + (height * 10.5);
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result + " rub.";
    } else {
        result = "Error.";
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Ширина :</p>
<input type="text" id="width">

<p>Высота (см): </p>
<input type="text" id="height">

<p>Цена: <span id="price"></span></p>

<button id="btn" onclick="getCalc()">Рассчитать</button>
```

В итоге на консоли появляется это:

> string
>   W <
>   0 >

В итоге становится понятно, что поле `.value` действительно возвращает строку! И если в той же консоли выполнить строку `"12" * 3` то получим 36 – умножение в JavaScript автоматически приводит строку к числу! Решение простое: для перевода строки в число добавьте слева от выражение знак плюса: `+document.getElementById("width").value`

---

Стоит отметить, что помимо этого в коде присутствуют очевидные логические неточности с if'ами, не взаимосвязанные проверки почему-то находятся в else, а также присутствует обнуление числа ошибок. Думаю, правильно сделать так:

```js
function getCalc() {
    var width = +document.getElementById("width").value;
    var height = +document.getElementById("height").value;

    // Теперь выводит number!
    console.log(typeof width);

    var max_width = 200;
    var min_width = 120;
    var max_height = 240;
    var min_height = 180;

    var result = 0;
    var errors = 0;

    // errors block
    if (width < min_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        // console.log('W <');
    }

    if (height < min_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        // console.log('H <');
    }

    if (width > max_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        // console.log('W >');
    }

    if (height > max_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;
        // console.log('H >');
    }

    if (errors <= 0) {
        result = (width * 15) + (height * 10.5);
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result + " rub.";
    } else {
        result = "Error.";
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Ширина :</p>
<input type="text" id="width">

<p>Высота (см): </p>
<input type="text" id="height">

<p>Цена: <span id="price"></span></p>

<button id="btn" onclick="getCalc()">Рассчитать</button>
```

Вводим 10, 20, получаем искомый `Error` :)

Answer (score 0):

Если дело в типах данных то можно преобразовать строку к числу например такая запись даст нам тип число `var width = +"123"; // number` Для сравнения `if(+width < +max_width)...`

Подробнее здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion

Хотя ваш код нормально работает, я просто добавил `<div id="price"></div>` в HTML

```js
function getCalc() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

    var max_width = 200;
    var min_width = 120;
    var max_height = 240;
    var min_height = 180;

    var result = 0;
    var errors = 0;

    // errors block
    if (width < min_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else if (height < min_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else {
        errors = 0;
    }

    if (width > max_width) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else if (height > max_height) {
        errors = errors + 1;

    } else {
        errors = 0;
    }
    if (errors <= 0) {
        result = (width * 15) + (height * 10.5);
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result + " rub.";
    } else {
        result = "Error.";
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Ширина :</p>
<input type="text" id="width">

<p>Высота (см): </p>
<input type="text" id="height">

<button id="btn" onclick="getCalc()">Рассчитать</button>

<div id="price"></div>
```